# Mapping Error related to trimming of signals

Tags: vhdl

I resolved the previous error but system is not allowing me to create a new question that's why i am editing the current one. Now i am getting an error in map like this:

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<1>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<3>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<2>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out23" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_cy<0>" which
   will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why
   the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<1>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<2>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_lut<3>"
   which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about
   why the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has input signal "Madd_frame_count_cy<0>" which
   will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why
   the input signal will become undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT5 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_F" (output signal=N8) has
   input signal "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of
   the Map Report File for details about why the input signal will become
   undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT4 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_G" (output signal=N9) has
   input signal "Madd_frame_count_cy<0>" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of
   the Map Report File for details about why the input signal will become
   undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT4 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_G" (output signal=N9) has
   input signal "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of
   the Map Report File for details about why the input signal will become
   undriven.
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has an equation that uses input pin I0, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has an equation that uses input pin I1, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out21) has an equation that uses input pin I2, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out23" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out22) has an equation that uses input pin I1, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has an equation that uses input pin I1, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has an equation that uses input pin I3, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has an equation that uses input pin I4, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out25" (output
   signal=Mmux_ac97_sdata_out24) has an equation that uses input pin I5, which
   no longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
   equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
   Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT5 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_F" (output signal=N8) has
   an equation that uses input pin I3, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT4 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_G" (output signal=N9) has
   an equation that uses input pin I0, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).
ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT4 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out29_G" (output signal=N9) has
   an equation that uses input pin I3, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

Full code in VHDL is:

```
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    14:35:54 02/28/2016 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    audioloopbackVHDL - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity audioloopbackVHDL is
port (
    clock           :in std_logic;
    ac97_sdata_out  :out std_logic;
    ac97_sdata_in   :in std_logic;
    ac97_sync       :out std_logic;
    audio_reset_b   :out std_logic;
    ac97_bit_clock  :in std_logic);
end audioloopbackVHDL;

architecture Behavioral of audioloopbackVHDL is
--attribute S: string;
--attribute S of ac97_sdata_out: signal is "TRUE";
signal abc : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal def : integer;
signal ghi : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal jkl : integer;
signal command_address : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0); 
signal command_data : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
signal bit_count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal frame_count : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal command : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal reset_count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal count : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
signal enable : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
signal en1 : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);

begin

process(clock)
begin
if(rising_edge(clock))then
    if(reset_count <= "11111111")then
       audio_reset_b <= '1';
    else
       reset_count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(reset_count) + 1 );
   end if;
end if;
end process;

process(bit_count, ac97_bit_clock, command_data, command_address, frame_count)
begin
  -- Generate the sync signal
  if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
    ac97_sync     <= '1';
  end if;
  if (bit_count <= "00001111")then
    ac97_sync     <= '0';
  end if;
  if ((bit_count >= "00000000") and (bit_count <= "00001111"))then
        -- Slot 0: Tags
    case bit_count is
          when "00000000" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000001" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000010" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when others     => ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
    end case;

  elsif ((bit_count >= "00010000") and (bit_count <= "00100011"))then
          -- Slot 1: Command address
    abc            <= std_logic_vector(35 - unsigned(bit_count));
    def            <= to_integer(unsigned(abc));
    ac97_sdata_out <= command_address(def);


  elsif ((bit_count >= "00100100") and (bit_count <= "00110111"))then
            -- Slot 2: Command data
    ghi            <= std_logic_vector(55 - unsigned(bit_count));
    jkl            <= to_integer(unsigned(ghi));
    ac97_sdata_out <= command_data(jkl);

  else
    ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
  end if;

  if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
    frame_count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frame_count) + 1);
    bit_count   <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(bit_count) + 1);
  end if;
end process;

process(frame_count, command, ac97_bit_clock, count, command_address, command_data, ac97_sdata_in)
begin
     case frame_count is
       when "0000" => command <= "000000100000000000000000"; -- Unmute line outputs
       when "0001" => command <= "000001000000000000000000"; -- Unmute headphones
       when "0010" => command <= "000100000000100000001000"; -- Unmute line inputs
       when others => command <= "111111000000000000000000"; -- Read vendor ID
     end case;



   -- Separate the address and data portions of the command
   -- and pad them to 20 bits
   command_address(19 downto 12) <= command(23 downto 16);
    command_address(11 downto 0) <= "000000000000";
   command_data(19 downto 4) <= command(15 downto 0);
    command_data(3 downto 0) <= "0000";
end process;


end architecture;
```

I am also attaching my ucf code:

```
NET "clock"          LOC="V10"  | IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS33 | CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE=FALSE;
#
# Audio CODEC
#

NET "audio_reset_b"  LOC="K15" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sdata_out" LOC="H18" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sdata_in"  LOC="J16" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sync"     LOC="K16" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_bit_clock" LOC="J18" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST  | CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE=FALSE;
```

Also, this ucf worked as desired when main program was in Verilog. Please help me out

Comment: Where is line 119? A propper indentation will show where the error is. VHDL is not C. There are no single line statements which need no end statements.

Comment: There is a difference between `else if` and `elsif`. The first one opens another group which must be closed by `end if`. And please always post a [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so that, one can identify line 119 and also check his/her solution for further errors.

Comment: One solution is to close all `if`s with `end if;` just before the `end process;`. But I think, this not what you want. So, please describe the intended behavior.

Comment: There are six `if`s an only one `end if`. Two of those `if`s look like they might be intended to be `elsif`s. On the other hand you have 9 pairs of superfluous parentheses.   See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For those interested in what's going on here See [Audio Codec ‘97 Revision 2.3](http://ece545.com/S16/resources/ac97_r23.pdf), 
4. AC-link Digital Interface.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the second process, the `if ... end if` ain't balanced, thus there are missing some `end if`'s.  There may be other issues also; as Peabbels asks; what is line 119 ?

Try to indent the code according to the control structure, since this easily shows syntax problems.  Using Emacs VHDL beautify shows the code like:

```
process(bit_count, ac97_sync, ac97_bit_clock, ac97_sdata_out, command_data, command_address, frame_count)
begin
  -- Generate the sync signal
  if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
    ac97_sync     <= '1';
    if (bit_count <= "00001111")then
      ac97_sync                                    <= '0';
      if ((bit_count >= "00000000") and (bit_count <= "00001111"))then
        -- Slot 0: Tags
        case bit_count is
          when "00000000" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000001" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000010" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when others     => ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
        end case;
      else
        if ((bit_count >= "00010000") and (bit_count <= "00100011"))then
          -- Slot 1: Command address
          abc            <= std_logic_vector(35 - unsigned(bit_count));
          def            <= to_integer(unsigned(abc));
          ac97_sdata_out <= command_address(def);
        else
          if ((bit_count >= "00100100") and (bit_count <= "00110111"))then
            -- Slot 2: Command data
            ghi            <= std_logic_vector(55 - unsigned(bit_count));
            jkl            <= to_integer(unsigned(ghi));
            ac97_sdata_out <= command_data(jkl);
          else
            ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
          end if;
          if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
            frame_count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frame_count) + 1);
            bit_count   <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(bit_count) + 1);
          end if;
end process;
```

Comment: hi morten zilmer and thanks for the reply. I have entered the code as you suggested with proper identation but still encountered the same error. Line with error is the last line "end process;"

Comment: The code is not the solution, but shows the problem, since it shows that the `if ... end if` are not balanced.  You need to balance these by correcting the code, probably adding some `end if`'s the right places.

Comment: thanks i have translated the code successfully but now i am getting this error in map:

Comment: You did not include the error information.  Anyway, if the new problem is unrelated to the previous, I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: Have you simulated this ?  If not then I suggest you make a very simple test bench for simulation, since that will often reveal basic design problems that may be the reason for the synthesis error.  If you have simulated it, then I suggest you look at the implementation of the expression used for the LUTs in the error, to determine why synthesis trims it.