# vhdl map error regarding trimming of signals

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a code in vhdl for audioloopback and getting an error in map like this:

> ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has input signal "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out23"
>   which
>      will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why
>      the input signal will become undriven.
>   ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has input signal "Madd_bit_count_lut<6>" which
>      will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why
>      the input signal will become undriven.
>   ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has input signal "Madd_bit_count_lut<7>" which
>      will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why
>      the input signal will become undriven.
>   ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has input signal
>      "bit_count[7]_GND_4_o_LessThan_9_o" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of
>      the Map Report File for details about why the input signal will become
>      undriven.
>   ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has input signal "ac97_sync_OBUF" which will be
>      trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why the input
>      signal will become undriven.
>   ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has an equation that uses input pin I0, which no
>      longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
>      equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
>      Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
>   ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has an equation that uses input pin I1, which no
>      longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
>      equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
>      Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
>   ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has an equation that uses input pin I2, which no
>      longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
>      equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
>      Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
>   ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has an equation that uses input pin I3, which no
>      longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
>      equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
>      Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).
>   ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT6 symbol "Mmux_ac97_sdata_out210" (output
>      signal=ac97_sdata_out_OBUF) has an equation that uses input pin I5, which no
>      longer has a connected signal. Please ensure that all the pins used in the
>      equation for this LUT have signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the
>      Map Report File for details on which signals were trimmed).

---

```
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    14:35:54 02/28/2016 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    audioloopbackVHDL - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity audioloopbackVHDL is
port (
    clock           :in std_logic;
    ac97_sdata_out  :out std_logic;
    ac97_sdata_in   :in std_logic;
    ac97_sync       :out std_logic;
    audio_reset_b   :out std_logic;
    ac97_bit_clock  :in std_logic);
end audioloopbackVHDL;

architecture Behavioral of audioloopbackVHDL is
--attribute S: string;
--attribute S of ac97_sdata_out: signal is "TRUE";
signal abc : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal def : integer;
signal ghi : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal jkl : integer;
signal command_address : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0); 
signal command_data : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
signal bit_count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal frame_count : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal command : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal reset_count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal count : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
signal enable : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
signal en1 : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);

begin

process(clock)
begin
if(rising_edge(clock))then
    if(reset_count <= "11111111")then
       audio_reset_b <= '1';
    else
       reset_count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(reset_count) + 1 );
   end if;
end if;
end process;


process(bit_count, ac97_bit_clock, command_data, command_address, frame_count)
begin
  -- Generate the sync signal
  if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
    ac97_sync     <= '1';
  end if;
  if (bit_count <= "00001111")then
    ac97_sync     <= '0';
  end if;
  if ((bit_count >= "00000000") and (bit_count <= "00001111"))then
        -- Slot 0: Tags
    case bit_count is
          when "00000000" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000001" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when "00000010" => ac97_sdata_out <= '1';
          when others     => ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
    end case;

  elsif ((bit_count >= "00010000") and (bit_count <= "00100011"))then
          -- Slot 1: Command address
    abc            <= std_logic_vector(35 - unsigned(bit_count));
    def            <= to_integer(unsigned(abc));
    ac97_sdata_out <= command_address(def);


  elsif ((bit_count >= "00100100") and (bit_count <= "00110111"))then
            -- Slot 2: Command data
    ghi            <= std_logic_vector(55 - unsigned(bit_count));
    jkl            <= to_integer(unsigned(ghi));
    ac97_sdata_out <= command_data(jkl);

  else
    ac97_sdata_out <= '0';
  end if;

  if (bit_count <= "11111111")then
    frame_count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frame_count) + 1);
    bit_count   <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(bit_count) + 1);
  end if;
end process;

process(frame_count, command, ac97_bit_clock, count, command_address, command_data, ac97_sdata_in)
begin
     case frame_count is
       when "0000" => command <= "000000100000000000000000"; -- Unmute line outputs
       when "0001" => command <= "000001000000000000000000"; -- Unmute headphones
       when "0010" => command <= "000100000000100000001000"; -- Unmute line inputs
       when others => command <= "111111000000000000000000"; -- Read vendor ID
     end case;



   -- Separate the address and data portions of the command
   -- and pad them to 20 bits
   command_address(19 downto 12) <= command(23 downto 16);
    command_address(11 downto 0) <= "000000000000";
   command_data(19 downto 4) <= command(15 downto 0);
    command_data(3 downto 0) <= "0000";
end process;


end architecture;
```

and ucf file is:

```
NET "clock"          LOC=V10  | IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS33 | CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE=FALSE;
#
# Audio CODEC
#

NET "audio_reset_b"  LOC=K15 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sdata_out"  LOC=H18 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sdata_in"  LOC=J16 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_sync"     LOC=K16 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST ;
NET "ac97_bit_clock" LOC=J18 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST  | CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE=FALSE;
```

Comment: please edit and reformat the topmost part of your question to be more readable. Probably use quoting.

Comment: While improved over [Syntax error near process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685134/syntax-error-near-process) you're still showing actual reliance on frame_count which incremented every bit. Still not actually using ac97_bit_clock, and at least some of these signals should be variables abc, def, ghi, jkl (because signal updates occur after all processes in the current simulation cycle has suspended). Make the counters unsigned types. It's premature to go to synthesis, simulate first, your code isn't functional and it only needs 1024 ac97_bit_clock intervals or so.  Team effort?

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least one) combinatorial loop in your design. Your third process from the top basically does

```
process (bit_count, frame_count)
begin
    frame_count <= frame_count + 1;
    bit_count <= bit_count + 1;
end process;
```

Did you forget to wait for your clock to change?

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I removed that process as I had already incremented frame_count and bit_count in another process. i have also tried as you suggested but error in maping isnt handled by that.

Comment: what do you mean  by "error in maping"? The messages basically say that the synthesizer optimized away most of your logic because there is no value driving it anymore. Difficult to tell if you don't show your updated code.

Comment: then you still have the same issue: your incrementing `bit_count` and `frame_count` unconditionally within the process.